# Array not matching the bottom part

Tags: modifiers

I have a curve and 2 array. The top part of array match will the bottom its not match to complete a circle. I increase the array count also. The top part match but bottom does not.

[image]

[image]

Any suggestion why its not working. Thanks

Comment: Test it in real life and you'll see that It's *working fine*. It's just you expecting something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is not clear, do you mean you'd like the pieces to merge to each others? They won't because your last modifier is an *Array* with *Object Offset* option, so it will just make your module repeat around the empty, without any deformation or merging.

So maybe you should apply the first and second modifiers and delete the last *Array*. Now apply the scale of the object, put its origin to its geometry. Give it a new *Array* with a *Relative Offset* of X : 1, and activate the *Merge* and *First Last* options. Also give it a new *Curve* modifier.

Duplicate a circle edge loop from the base of your vase, make it another object, delete its modifiers, convert to curve.

[image]

Put your first object at the center of the curve. Give it a *Curve* modifier with the circle as *Object*. Set the *Array Fit Type* to *Fit Curve* and choose the curve. Move your object a bit so that it fits the vase radius.

[image]

You could as well use a *Simple Deform* modifier, *Bend* mode, instead of the Curve modifier.